# No difference between Logistic Regression model and Ensemble models (Bagging and Boosting)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, ensemble-learning, adaboost

I was trying to compare a logistic regression model and some ensemble models (bagging and boosting) with logistic regression as their base estimator. But, surprisingly, I got the same score for all three classifiers:

- `LogisticRegression()`
- `BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=LogisticRegression())`
- `AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=LogisticRegression())`

This is my code, please help me.

```py
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(x_train, y_train).score(x_test, y_test)

bagging_clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=LogisticRegression(), n_estimators=50, bootstrap=True)
bagging_clf.fit(x_train, y_train).score(x_test, y_test)

adaboost_clf = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=LogisticRegression(), learning_rate=1, n_estimators=50)
adaboost_clf.fit(x_train, y_train).score(x_test, y_test)
```

The score is 0.9063627039010026 for all classifiers.

Comment: You pass to all your estimators the same LogisticRegression object, the one referenced by lr. I guess they all manipulate the same object, and you basically get the results of the last estimator. Try to replace base-estimator=lr with base_estimator=LogisticRegression(), so that each estimator gets its own object to work with.

Comment: Thanks, i've tried replacing the base_estimator and the result still doesn't change. I've tried using DecisionTreeClassifier() for the base_model and it gives a different result for each model (Bagging = 0.935810475465705, AdaBoost = 0.8818118651358237,and the DecisionTreeClassifier itself gives 0.8816795156007015)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bagging and boosting work well with very overfit and very underfit base models, respectively.  Doing either with logistic regression is unlikely to have a dramatic effect.  You probably do get some changes, but you're only reporting the `score`, which by default will be the accuracy score; if your test size is smallish, then there aren't too many different values possible.